# Two cursors mirrored with click

Tags: mouse-cursor

I am looking for a way to have 2 cursors that move simultaneously with one mouse. Also with simultaneous click and hold action.
Im trying to use it for art project where i have 2 windows open ( a reference image to trace and photoshop in other window.)
The goal is to trace the reference image with the 1st cursors while displaying it in photoshop with 2nd cursor.
I have tried TeamPlayer program that gives me 2 cursors, but they dont move simultaneously and you need 2 mice to control each cursor.

Comment: When you click or right click on one photoshop side, what happens on the other side? And when you _hold_? (maybe you mean drag).

Comment: Put the image in Photoshop, add a layer on top, trace away.

Comment: Do you mean two cursors that move simultaneously with one mouse, both moving and clicking at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Velcro two mice together? Make a frame to hold them together with Popsicle sticks and/or duct tape? If no software solution presents itself, there's always The Kludge.